# Помогите понять Адаптивный дизайн

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, media-queries

Всем добрый вечер, Нуждаюсь в помощи опытных пользователей , прочитал уже множество статей про Адаптивный дизайн и даже адаптировал сайт под разные устройства , но проблема только в одном.
Когда я задаю 
`@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1366px) { ...}`

Размеры сайта адаптируется под разрешение 1366px(отступы margin,padding и все такое) но при проверке на 1200px , он отображается криво , 
может ли кто - то доходчиво объяснить как реализовывать адаптивный дизайн с диапазоном разрешений , ато так приходится под каждое разрешение адаптировать , а их очень много, да и когда в браузере уменьшаешь масштаб в некоторых размерах сайт выглядит криво.
Спасибо За внимание , жду ваших советов.

Comment: Флексбокс почитайте

Answer (score 2):

**1/** Правильная последовательность медиазапросов.

От меньшего к большему (min-width: 768px --> 1200px --> 1366pxpx):

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  ...
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  ...
}
@media (min-width: 1366pxpx) {
  ...
}
```

От большего к меньшему (max-width: 1366pxpx --> 1200px --> 768px):

```
@media (max-width: 1366px) {
  ...
}    
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  ...
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  ...
}
```

*Мне такая схема помогает запомнить.*

---

**2/** Адаптация оберток (.wrap, .container) и других блоков.

```
.wrap { 
  max-width: 1200px; 
  width: 100%; 
}
```

или

```
.container {  
  width: 90%; 
}
```

---

**3/** Адаптация изображений и других медиаобъектов

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

---

**4/** Расположение блоков

Отмена `float` если нужно, применение `flex` или другой разметки.

---

**5/** Различные другие факторы (лишние отступы, фиксированная ширина блоков, шрифт, ...)

---

Еще рекомендуется использовать `box-sizing` (не совсем с адаптацией связано, просто совет)

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

---

Простыми словами, смысл в том, что адаптивная верстка предусматривает нормальное отображение сайта на различных устройства (планшеты, телефоны). Т.е. возможно изменение размеров блоков, шрифтов. Изменение расположения блоков.

---

**P.S:** *Все относительно и обобщенно. Для каждого случая нужно смотреть в чем проблема.*

**СОВЕТ:** На просторах интернета уже уйма уроков и примеров адаптивной верстки, посмотрите!

Comment: Спасибо , очень полезная информация , попробую как вы сказали

Comment: Дополню. Возможны баги при использовании сочетаний со смежными значениями для media. Например +media screen and (min-width:100px) and (max-width:200px){...} +media screen and (min-width:200px) and (max-width:300px){...}, лучше заменить на +media screen and (min-width:100px) and (max-width:199px){...} +media screen and (min-width:200px) and (max-width:299px){...} итд. в противном случае, в том самом 1пиксельном диапазоне будут неожиданности.